# org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException in POI API after an .xls file is updated with Libre Office

Tags: java, excel, exception, apache-poi

I am reading an Excel using POI api, I use the following code to read the excel file.

```
    public class ExcelWorkBook {

        private static ExcelWorkBook excelWorkBook = null;
        private static String filePath;
        private static XSSFWorkbook workbook;

        /**
         * This  constructor used to initialize the {@link ExcelWorkBook}
         * @throws IOException
         */
        private ExcelWorkBook() throws IOException {
            try {
                workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(getFile());
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ExcelWorkBook.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }

        /**
         * This method create a new object {@link ExcelWorkBook}
         * @return {@link ExcelWorkBook}
         * @throws IOException
         */
        public static ExcelWorkBook getInstance() throws IOException {
            excelWorkBook = new ExcelWorkBook();
            return excelWorkBook;
        }

        /**
         * This method create a {@link FileInputStream}
         * @return {@link FileInputStream}
         * @throws FileNotFoundException
         */
        private FileInputStream getFile() throws FileNotFoundException {
          FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath));
          return file;
        }
        .
        .
        .
        .
```

But its throwing following exception in a particular file which is created using MS Office 2010 and undated using Libre office. What could Be the problem. The Stack trace of exception is attached below

```
 org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFactory.createDocumentPart(XSSFFactory.java:61) ~[poi-ooxml-3.7.jar:3.7]
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocumentPart.read(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:277) ~[poi-ooxml-3.7.jar:3.7]
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocumentPart.read(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:282) ~[poi-ooxml-3.7.jar:3.7]
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:186) ~[poi-ooxml-3.7.jar:3.7]
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:189) ~[poi-ooxml-3.7.jar:3.7]
    at com.excel.ExcelWorkBook.<init>(ExcelWorkBook.java:48) 
    at com.excel.ExcelWorkBook.getInstance(ExcelWorkBook.java:60) 
    at com.excel.ExcelParser.<init>(ExcelParser.java:64) 
    at com.database.DatabaseLoader.process(DatabaseLoader.java:85) 
    at com.fileuploader.FileUploadHandler.doPost(FileUploadHandler.java:116) 
.
.
.
.
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [na:1.6.0_45]
[STDOUT] Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
[STDOUT]    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_45]
[STDOUT]    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39) ~[na:1.6.0_45]
[STDOUT]    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27) ~[na:1.6.0_45]
[STDOUT]    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513) ~[na:1.6.0_45]
[STDOUT]    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFactory.createDocumentPart(XSSFFactory.java:59) ~[poi-ooxml-3.7.jar:3.7]
[STDOUT]    ... 42 common frames omitted
[STDOUT] Caused by: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: error: duplicate attribute 'type'
[STDOUT]    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale$SaxLoader.load(Locale.java:3471) ~[xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar:na]
[STDOUT]    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.parseToXmlObject(Locale.java:1270) ~[xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar:na]
[STDOUT]    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.parseToXmlObject(Locale.java:1257) ~[xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar:na]
[STDOUT]    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeLoaderBase.parse(SchemaTypeLoaderBase.java:345) ~[xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar:na]
[STDOUT]    at org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject$Factory.parse(XmlObject.java:663) ~[xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0-r540734]
[STDOUT]    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFVMLDrawing.read(XSSFVMLDrawing.java:107) ~[poi-ooxml-3.7.jar:3.7]
[STDOUT]    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFVMLDrawing.<init>(XSSFVMLDrawing.java:102) ~[poi-ooxml-3.7.jar:3.7]
[STDOUT]    ... 47 common frames omitted
[STDOUT] Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: duplicate attribute 'type'
[STDOUT]    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.Piccolo.reportFatalError(Piccolo.java:1038) ~[xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar:na]
[STDOUT]    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.Piccolo.parse(Piccolo.java:723) ~[xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar:na]
[STDOUT]    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale$SaxLoader.load(Locale.java:3439) ~[xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar:na]
[STDOUT]    ... 53 common frames omitted
```

Comment: The exception seems to indicate that the file has invalid XML in it. Are you sure it's a valid and un-corrupted file?

Comment: The only one thing I done additionaly is, I have edited that excel file with libre office. Is there a chance of corruption by it?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. It hapen as soon as I edit my xlsx file in Libre Office. Althoug I get some more debugging info from org.xml.sax.SAXParseException in the end, It looks like Libre does something that makes duplicate tags
`Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 344; duplicate attribute 'type'
 at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.Piccolo.reportFatalError(Piccolo.java:1038)
 at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.Piccolo.parse(Piccolo.java:723)
 at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale$SaxLoader.load(Locale.java:3439)
`

Comment: I have same issue. Don't exactly know what will solve solve this issue!!?? I get this issue with .xlsx files with comments. Without comments, even if edited in libre, it seems to be working fine.

Comment: I had the same issue with libreoffice 4.2.8. The error was due to comments I had added. The version 5.1 solves the issue.

Comment: In my case when I re-saved the excel spreadsheet then uploaded it worked without issues.

Answer (score 4):

I had exactly the same exception after I edited with Libe Office a .xlsx file containing comments. The removal of the comments solved the issue.

Comment: For one my files, removing comments as suggested fixed the problem. For a second XLSX file however I had to go one step further. After opening the file in LibreCalc, I saved it in xls format, then opened the xls and saved it as xlsx. That seemed to remove all the hidden garbage that was causing POI problems. FWIW, I think the underlying problem is that Excel allows other Office constructs (e.g. docs with drawings) to be embedded as comments.

Answer (score 4):

Your Excel will be parsed into XML first.
This exception happens when the xml is invalid. This can be the case when you create the Excel Sheet with Microsoft Office and then edit the Sheet with some other Software like Libre or Open office.

I don't know what it is that Open Office or Libre Office  do, but they do something to the document that POI doesn't like.

Use Microsoft Excel to read or edit your sheets.
It worked for me, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

I have inserted org.apache.xmlbeans in project. It helped.

Comment: In my case, this solved my problem.  I had apparently updated Excel to a version that my current install of Apache POI could no longer support.  I upgraded the version of POI that my project used to version 3.14, easily fixed the few ClassDefNotFound errors that this (hastily installed) upgrade caused and then encountered the error described by the OP.  Upgrading xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar to xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar solved this problem.