# Is there a limitation reading XLSX file using SoapUI free version 5.3.0 & Apache poi-3.14?

Tags: groovy, apache-poi, soapui

Is there a limitation reading XLSX file?  With XLS file, i face no problems.

**My Environment is:**

- SoapUI free version 5.3.0
- Apache POI 3.14
- Windows 7 Pro/ Office 2010

**Location of Apache POI libraries**

```
I unzipped the downloaded POI package into the following folder:
C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.3.0\bin\ext
fyi - I have also tried adding it to lib
```

**The error i get when i try to run the groovy script provided below is:**

```
org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

**My Groovy Script is:**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.Iterator;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;

String filepath = "E:\\SoapUiProjects\\MyWorkspace\\data\\data.XLSX"
String sheetName = "login"
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(filepath))

Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(fis)
Sheet sh = wb.getSheet(sheetName)

Iterator itrRow = sh.rowIterator()
while(itrRow.hasNext())
{
    Row row = itrRow.next()
    for(Cell cell : row)
    {
        switch(cell.getCellType())
        {
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                log.info cell.getNumericCellValue()
                break;
            default:
                log.info cell.getRichStringCellValue()
        }       
    }   
}

fis.close()
wb.close()
```

**The Stacktrace:**

```
2017-07-11 15:09:50,631 ERROR [SoapUI] An error occurred [java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException], see error log for details
2017-07-11 15:09:50,631 ERROR [errorlog] org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLFactory.createDocumentPart(POIXMLFactory.java:65)
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocumentPart.read(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:601)
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:174)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:249)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:211)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:170)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory$create.call(Unknown Source)
    at Script21.run(Script21.groovy:14)
    at com.eviware.soapui.support.scripting.groovy.SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.run(SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.java:90)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.WsdlGroovyScriptTestStep.run(WsdlGroovyScriptTestStep.java:141)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.panels.teststeps.GroovyScriptStepDesktopPanel$RunAction$1.run(GroovyScriptStepDesktopPanel.java:250)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFactory.createDocumentPart(XSSFFactory.java:56)
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLFactory.createDocumentPart(POIXMLFactory.java:62)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.poi.POIXMLTypeLoader
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.model.ThemesTable.<init>(ThemesTable.java:85)
    ... 19 more
```

Thank You in advance.

Comment: What is the full stacktrace of the error?

Comment: Where did you copy the `apache-poi` libraries? Have you restarted soapui after that? Have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25364338/org-apache-poi-poixmlexception-java-lang-reflect-invocationtargetexception-in-p)?

Comment: @Rao, I unzipped the downloaded POI package into the following folder:
`C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.3.0\bin\ext`
fyi - I have also tried adding it to lib

Comment: Just keep in `bin\ext` directory, not required to copy under `lib`. Hope you restarted soapui after that. Full stacktrace please.

Comment: @Gagravarr, @Rao, the stacktrace is now appended to the original question. The poi library is added to `bin/ext` only and soapui is restarted. I also continue to refer  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25364338/org-apache-poi-poixmlexception-java-lang-reflect-invocationtargetexception-in-p) without able to find a resolution. Please help.

Comment: `a note: thought it might be useful.` I also have no problem reading the xlsx file using the same poi libraries from a java class in eclipse.

Comment: https://forums.mulesoft.com/questions/45379/could-not-initialize-class-orgapachepoipoixmltypel.html

Comment: @Rao, i checked the solution in the link provided. I already have the latest version of `poi-ooxml-3.14-20160307.jar` in `bin/ext`. The same error still shows. Did i miss something?

Comment: @BipoK, are you still facing issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Below exception thrown when **poi-ooxml** jar is not available

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.poi.POIXMLTypeLoader
```

I have added below libraries to soap UI ext folder.

```
C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.3.0\bin\ext
```

**Libraries**

```
commons-collections4-4.1.jar
ooxml-schemas-1.3.jar
ooxml-security-1.1.jar
openxml4j-1.0-beta.jar
poi-3.16.jar
poi-contrib-3.6.jar
poi-examples-3.16.jar
poi-excelant-3.16.jar
poi-ooxml-3.16.jar
poi-ooxml-schemas-3.16.jar
poi-scratchpad-3.16.jar
```

Your code works fine for me.

**Groovy code**:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.Iterator;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;

String filepath = "D:\\testdata\\TestData.xlsx"
String sheetName = "Sheet1"
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(filepath))

Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(fis)
Sheet sh = wb.getSheet(sheetName)

Iterator itrRow = sh.rowIterator()
while(itrRow.hasNext())
{
    Row row = itrRow.next()
    for(Cell cell : row)
    {
        switch(cell.getCellType())
        {
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                log.info cell.getNumericCellValue()
                break;
            default:
                log.info cell.getRichStringCellValue()
        }       
    }   
}

fis.close()
wb.close()
```

**Output:**

```
Sat Jul 29 08:00:54 SGT 2017:INFO:VarName
Sat Jul 29 08:00:54 SGT 2017:INFO:URL
Sat Jul 29 08:00:54 SGT 2017:INFO:DBURL
Sat Jul 29 08:00:54 SGT 2017:INFO:https://www.stackoverflow.com
Sat Jul 29 08:00:54 SGT 2017:INFO:Test
```

Comment: I got error message: `org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLException: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlOptions.setEntityExpansionLimit(I)Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/XmlOptions; error at line: 14`